# How do i put the specified contents of XML file into a jquery array using ajax?

Tags: jquery, arrays

Hi im new to jquery or javascript not sure what the difference is.. and im trying read an xml file and display certain values from that xml into a dropdown list(a select). The ajax method im using reads the xml ok, however in my drop down list i have multiple identical entries, so i need to put these entries into some sort of container and loop through them to remove them.
So far i have

```
var XML_MAP_PATH = "/resources/XML/MapInformationXML.xml";
var selectedSiteName;
var buildingName;
$(document).ready(function () {

//Clear all drop down lists
$('#cboSiteNames >option').remove();

$('#cboFloors >option').remove();

//Read XML file and populate cboSiteNames drop down list
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    url: XML_MAP_PATH,
    context: document.body,
    dataType: "xml",
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    success: function (xml) { //If data is available(success) then..
        $(xml).find('Map').each(function () { //go to parent node in xml
            siteName = $(this).attr("Site"); //add all site names to siteName var

            $("#cboSiteNames").append($('<option></option>').attr("value", siteName).text(siteName)); //add values to dropdownlist

        });
    }
});
});
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MapInformation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Map Map_Name="New Mills" Site="New Mills" BuldingName="Mill" FloorNumber="0" ImageFilePath="C:\Users\--\SourceControl\Work\XSD\XSD stuff\XSD stuff\Images\NewMills0.png" />
  <Map Map_Name="New Mills" Site="New Mills" BuldingName="Mill" FloorNumber="1" ImageFilePath="C:\Users\--\SourceControl\Work\XSD\XSD stuff\XSD stuff\Images\NewMills1.png" />
  <Map Map_Name="New Mills" Site="New Mills" BuldingName="Mill" FloorNumber="2" ImageFilePath="C:\Users\--\SourceControl\Work\XSD\XSD stuff\XSD stuff\Images\NewMills2.png" />
  <Map Map_Name="New Mills" Site="New Mills" BuldingName="Round Tower" FloorNumber="0" ImageFilePath="C:\Users\--\SourceControl\Work\XSD\XSD stuff\XSD stuff\Images\NewMills0.png" />
  <Map Map_Name="New Mills" Site="New Mills" BuldingName="Round Tower" FloorNumber="1" ImageFilePath="C:\Users\--\SourceControl\Work\XSD\XSD stuff\XSD stuff\Images\NewMills1.png" />
  <Map Map_Name="New Mills" Site="New Mills" BuldingName="Round Tower" FloorNumber="2" ImageFilePath="C:\Users\--\SourceControl\Work\XSD\XSD stuff\XSD stuff\Images\NewMills2.png" />
  <Map Map_Name="Charfield" Site="Charfield" BuldingName="GES" FloorNumber="1" ImageFilePath="C:\Users\--\SourceControl\Work\XSD\XSD stuff\XSD stuff\Images\Charfield1.png" />
  <Map Map_Name="Miskin" Site="Miskin" BuldingName="Miskin Building 1" FloorNumber="0" ImageFilePath="C:\Users\--\SourceControl\Work\XSD\XSD stuff\XSD stuff\Images\NewMills2.png" />
  <Map Map_Name="Miskin" Site="Miskin" BuldingName="Miskin Building 2" FloorNumber="1" ImageFilePath="C:\Users\--\SourceControl\Work\XSD\XSD stuff\XSD stuff\Images\Charfield1.png" />
</MapInformation>
```

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library, JavaScript is the language. jQuery is useful functions written in JavaScript so that you don't have to, it is not a language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid duplicate entries you should create an empty object and use it to keep track of duplicates. Before you create an `option` element check if a property of its value exists on the object if it doesn't create the element and add its value as a property to the object.

This is far more efficient than creating the elements and then looping through and removing them.

**Change:**

```
success: function (xml) { //If data is available(success) then..
        $(xml).find('Map').each(function () { //go to parent node in xml
            siteName = $(this).attr("Site"); //add all site names to siteName var

            $("#cboSiteNames").append($('<option></option>').attr("value", siteName).text(siteName)); //add values to dropdownlist

        });
    }
```

**To:**

```
success: function (xml) { //If data is available(success) then..
        var map = {};
        $(xml).find('Map').each(function () { //go to parent node in xml
            siteName = $(this).attr("Site"); //add all site names to siteName var

            if (!map.hasOwnProperty(siteName)) { // Check if siteName already exists
                map.siteName = true; // Set the siteName property on map to avoid duplicates
                $("#cboSiteNames").append($('<option></option>').attr("value", siteName).text(siteName)); //add values to dropdownlist
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i made a slight change on George's code which helped massively. Here's what i did to make this work without using properties to check against.

```
 success: function (xml) { //If data is available(success) then..
            var map = [];
            $(xml).find('Map').each(function () { //go to parent node in xml
                siteName = $(this).attr("Site"); //add all site names to siteName var
                if ($.inArray(siteName, map) == -1) {
                    map.push(siteName);
                    $("#cboSiteNames").append($('<option></option>').attr("value", siteName).text(siteName)); //add values to dropdownlist
                }
```

Comment: This is much less efficient than my version. You reiterate through the array each time to check `$.inArray()` whereas an object look up is `O(1)` very fast doesn't require you to iterate over all the elements. Why don't you want to use an object? In an object you know the location to look for, in an array you don't and have to check every single item and then do an additional string comparison on each element, hence why it is much less efficient.